# How to improve the sounds on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, realtek

When I used to run the Windows on my laptop, I had installed a software called "Realtek" sound, or something like this, and the sound produced was much improved. Now, with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in the same computer, the sound is not so good as it was with Windows. Is there something I can do for improving it?

Answer (score 1):

I know what you're talking about, you mean Equalizer `Presets` modes as like Sound Manager, right? This feauture is not that necessary in Ubuntu, the sound itself configured for its best normal state. But yet you can change Equalizer at apps preferences if you want so, for example in SMPlayer `right click on a screen` > `audio` > `equalizer` you can choose different presets that suits you the best. Yet, also you can install `Pulse Audio Equalizer` with help of `PPA`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Hope that works for you. Good luck.